# Can't find a specific Melody Search Engine Website that I have seen before

Tags: classical-music, melody

I have been searching now already for quite a long time a website that does a similar job as the following websites:

- [Peachnote](http://www.peachnote.com/#!nt=singleNoteAffine&npq=62+0+1+2)
- [Musipedia](https://www.musipedia.org/)

Unfortunately, these websites are not what I am looking for.
Basically on that website, the user could click into a prepared / empty common music notation template to enter a custom melody. Then after clicking on a Search Button, it would search for melody matches. The overall layout of that website had a brownish design and I think but I am very unsure that the underlying data was about chorales (but I may be easily mistaken about that).

A website which is very close to what I am looking for is [Hymnary](https://hymnary.org/melody/search). The website that I am looking for presents at the beginning a single empty stave which allows the user to just click into the staff to enter notes one after the other.

During my search I found the following websites, but none of them is the tool that I am looking for:

- [Nooknet](https://nooknet.net/tunes)
- [ThemeFinder](http://www.themefinder.org/)

Is there something I am overlooking here? I would be very grateful, if you may be able to discover the website that I am looking for. I think the website is already a bit older, since it did not have the newest design.

EDIT1: The website I am looking for looks almost exactly like [CantusIndex](http://cantusindex.org/melody)

Comment: After some detailed search using the - operator of google search I was able to find it!

It's called GlobalChant; http://globalchant.org/search.php

Comment: Hi Byebb, if you would, please post "Global Chant" as an answer to this question (you can answer your own question) and then accept it as the correct answer (you may need to wait a day before this becomes an option). This will help us by showing this question correctly in our system as an answered question.

Comment: I hope, I did it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.
The website I was looking for is [Global Chant](http://globalchant.org/search.php)